# Windows hibernation: why lubuntu is prevented to mount a partition on which the hiberfil.sys is not present?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, lubuntu, hibernate

I am aware why linux doesn't mount the hibernated windows system partition -- due to the hibernation flag. As far as I am aware, the hiberfil.sys is stored on windows system partition, then why does it prevent linux from mounting a different partition?

I have 4 partitions:

- Lubuntu
- Windows
- Windows backup
- DATA (file storage)

Basically, I couldn't care less for the windows system partition, I don't even mount it on linux. All I care about is sharing my files on both windows and linux through the DATA partition. Is there a way to achieve this while retaining the possibility of hibernating windows?

Comment: Hibernation marks all open filesystems as dirty, that's why they can't be mounted. You can, however, mount it read-only, allowing you to access but not modify files.

Comment: Hmm.. I feared so. Is there no way to go about this? Why is it making all of the partitions flagged? What's the point?

Answer (score 3):

*I found a solution to my question on my own.*

> **SOLUTION**
>
> **Wrote in terminal:**
>
> ```
> sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
> ```

*where sdXY is the partition I needed to mount, in my case - DATA partition.
With this I can hibernate windows and still be able to use the DATA partition on lubuntu without losing the hibernated data on windows, which is on windows system partition.*

Comment: Anyone following this advice: this WILL remove anything that was placed in the hiberfile and not yet saved by Windows. doton doton might not care about what happens but you have been warned.

Answer (score -1):

The short answer to the question: "why lubuntu is prevented to mount a partition on which the hiberfil.sys is not present?":

> Making changes to your Windows (ntfs) partition while it is hibernated could be dangerous--it could cause Windows to not resume from hibernation or to crash after resuming.

I only quoted this from the much more detailed answer https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/865596. (But I think this is correct because it sounds very reasonable and it got many upvotes)

Some people (with reputation 20 000+) say that writing on a hibernation flagged NTFS partition (for example by using code like "sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY") can result in data loss on the NTFS data partition. (see answers of [Unable to load Windows(8.x) Partition in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659728/unable-to-load-windows8-x-partition-in-ubuntu) or in the comments of https://askubuntu.com/a/532753/865596 or https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364784)

In https://askubuntu.com/a/532753/865596 people say that the solution https://askubuntu.com/a/552232/865596 can be very dangerous (see explanation in https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/865596).

I think https://askubuntu.com/a/145904/865596, https://askubuntu.com/a/843161/865596 and maybe https://askubuntu.com/a/843373/865596 might be safer solutions, but I am not an expert. I got to these solutions from https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364784&s=6b0a085ceec98b88abc61f5d1e97ae5e&p=13660216#post13660216

This question might be related to my question [Is dual-boot Windows 10 with hibernation and Ubunutu 18.04 dangerous?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070689/is-dual-boot-windows-10-with-hibernation-and-ubunutu-18-04-dangerous) too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! I tried to improve my answer using your advice.